# How do I set cookies in Load Impact?

Tags: cookies, scripting, performance-testing, load-testing

*We’ve come across this question fairly often at Load Impact, so I’m adding it to the Stack Overflow community to make it easier to find*

Q: When performing a Load Impact load test, I need to have the VUs send cookies with their requests. How do I set a cookie for a VU?

Answer (score 0):

Load Impact VUs will automatically save and use cookies sent to them by the server (through the "Set-Cookie:" header). When the user scenario executed by the VU ends and gets restarted (i.e. starts a new user scenario script iteration), cookies stored by the VU/client will be cleared.

Cookies, or more specifically the “Cookie:” header, is currently the only header that is set automatically by the client. Other headers, such as e.g. “If-Modified-Since:” will not be set unless the user specifies it in the load script (this is why caching is not emulated automatically - client caching behaviour has to be programmed).

You can't manipulate the stored cookies that the VU client has, but you can override or set a cookie used by the client if you specify the "Cookie:" header in the requests you make, like this:

```
http.request_batch({
   {"GET", "http://example.com/", headers={["Cookie"]="name=value"}}
})
```